# xcode Crashes while doing My project ->Target-> Info

Tags: xcode6

Its crashing while clicking **info** tab only, the other tabs are working fine.

I get this detail report

```
Process:               Xcode [2020]
Path:                  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
Identifier:            com.apple.dt.Xcode
Version:               6.3.2 (7718)
Build Info:            IDEFrameworks-7718000000000000~2
App Item ID:           497799835
App External ID:       812404257
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           Xcode [2020]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2015-06-22 11:59:51.888 +0530
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.10 (14A389)
Report Version:        11
Anonymous UUID:        19E78DC8-A48F-6AC2-2A95-1D7EF8109C27


Time Awake Since Boot: 8500 seconds

Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000

Application Specific Information:
ProductBuildVersion: 6D2105
ASSERTION FAILURE in /SourceCache/IDEXcode3ProjectSupport/IDEXcode3ProjectSupport-7706/Xcode3UI/Editing/TargetInfo/Controllers/Xcode3InfoArraySliceController.m:256
Details:  dict should be an instance inheriting from NSDictionary, but it is <__NSCFString: 0x7ff6c05a4580>
Object:   <Xcode3InfoArraySliceController: 0x7ff6cc98bb60>
Method:   -setInfo:
Thread:   <NSThread: 0x7ff6c0720ea0>{number = 1, name = main}
Hints:   None
Backtrace:
  0  0x00000001053b9b6a -[IDEAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:fileName:lineNumber:assertionSignature:messageFormat:arguments:] (in IDEKit)
  1  0x00000001041085df _DVTAssertionHandler (in DVTFoundation)
  2  0x00000001041088ce _DVTAssertionFailureHandler (in DVTFoundation)
  3  0x000000011048072a -[Xcode3InfoArraySliceController setInfo:] (in Xcode3UI)
  4  0x000000011047eca7 -[Xcode3InfoArraySliceController initWithSliceIdentifier:infoArray:infoEditor:] (in Xcode3UI)
  5  0x000000011042fc9e -[Xcode3InfoEditor _createSubviews] (in Xcode3UI)
  6  0x0000000110431300 __42-[Xcode3InfoEditor setInspectedBlueprint:]_block_invoke_2 (in Xcode3UI)
  7  0x00007fff8e4892e8 __NSBLOCKOPERATION_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ (in Foundation)
  8  0x00007fff8e375905 -[NSBlockOperation main] (in Foundation)
  9  0x00007fff8e35459c -[__NSOperationInternal _start:] (in Foundation)
 10  0x00007fff8e3541a3 __NSOQSchedule_f (in Foundation)
 11  0x00007fff8d211c13 _dispatch_client_callout (in libdispatch.dylib)
 12  0x00007fff8d21dcbf _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF (in libdispatch.dylib)
 13  0x00007fff832ffc59 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ (in CoreFoundation)
 14  0x00007fff832bc2ef __CFRunLoopRun (in CoreFoundation)
 15  0x00007fff832bb838 CFRunLoopRunSpecific (in CoreFoundation)
 16  0x00007fff8aa1943f RunCurrentEventLoopInMode (in HIToolbox)
 17  0x00007fff8aa191ba ReceiveNextEventCommon (in HIToolbox)
 18  0x00007fff8aa18ffb _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter (in HIToolbox)
 19  0x00007fff89ebb821 _DPSNextEvent (in AppKit)
 20  0x00007fff89ebafd0 -[NSApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] (in AppKit)
 21  0x000000010468caaa -[DVTApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] (in DVTKit)
 22  0x00007fff89eaef73 -[NSApplication run] (in AppKit)
 23  0x00007fff89e9a424 NSApplicationMain (in AppKit)
 24  0x00007fff88a625c9 start (in libdyld.dylib)
 25  0x0000000000000001

abort() called

Application Specific Signatures:
[(id)(dict) isKindOfClass:[[NSDictionary class] class]]

Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff854bd282 __pthread_kill + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff85ac3b73 abort + 129
2   com.apple.dt.IDEKit             0x00000001053b9753 +[IDEAssertionHandler _handleAssertionWithLogString:assertionSignature:assertionReason:extraBacktrace:] + 1507
3   com.apple.dt.IDEKit             0x00000001053b9d20 -[IDEAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:fileName:lineNumber:assertionSignature:messageFormat:arguments:] + 1169
4   com.apple.dt.DVTFoundation      0x00000001041085df _DVTAssertionHandler + 367
5   com.apple.dt.DVTFoundation      0x00000001041088ce _DVTAssertionFailureHandler + 407
6   com.apple.dt.IDE.Xcode3UI       0x000000011048072a -[Xcode3InfoArraySliceController setInfo:] + 598
7   com.apple.dt.IDE.Xcode3UI       0x000000011047eca7 -[Xcode3InfoArraySliceController initWithSliceIdentifier:infoArray:infoEditor:] + 906
8   com.apple.dt.IDE.Xcode3UI       0x000000011042fc9e -[Xcode3InfoEditor _createSubviews] + 1349
9   com.apple.dt.IDE.Xcode3UI       0x0000000110431300 __42-[Xcode3InfoEditor setInspectedBlueprint:]_block_invoke_2 + 92
10  com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8e4892e8 __NSBLOCKOPERATION_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 7
11  com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8e375905 -[NSBlockOperation main] + 97
12  com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8e35459c -[__NSOperationInternal _start:] + 653
13  com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8e3541a3 __NSOQSchedule_f + 184
14  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff8d211c13 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
15  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff8d21dcbf _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 861
16  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff832ffc59 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 9
17  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff832bc2ef __CFRunLoopRun + 2159
18  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff832bb838 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 296
19  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff8aa1943f RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 235
20  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff8aa191ba ReceiveNextEventCommon + 431
21  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff8aa18ffb _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter + 71
22  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff89ebb821 _DPSNextEvent + 964
23  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff89ebafd0 -[NSApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 194
24  com.apple.dt.DVTKit             0x000000010468caaa -[DVTApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 237
25  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff89eaef73 -[NSApplication run] + 594
26  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff89e9a424 NSApplicationMain + 1832
27  libdyld.dylib                   0x00007fff88a625c9 start + 1

Thread 1:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff854be22e kevent64 + 10
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff8d214a6a _dispatch_mgr_thread + 52

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff854b852e mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff854b769f mach_msg + 55
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff832bcb14 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 212
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff832bbfdb __CFRunLoopRun + 1371
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff832bb838 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 296
5   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8e3b6ab9 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 278
6   com.apple.DTDeviceKitBase       0x000000010e3c6f3c -[DTDKRemoteDeviceDataListener listenerThreadImplementation] + 974
7   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8e3b4b7a __NSThread__main__ + 1345
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8fc2e2fc _pthread_body + 131
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8fc2e279 _pthread_start + 176
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8fc2c4b1 thread_start + 13

Thread 3:: com.apple.CFSocket.private
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff854bd3f6 __select + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8fc2e2fc _pthread_body + 131
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8fc2e279 _pthread_start + 176
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8fc2c4b1 thread_start + 13

Thread 4:: com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff854b852e mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff854b769f mach_msg + 55
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff832bcb14 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 212
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff832bbfdb __CFRunLoopRun + 1371
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff832bb838 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 296
5   com.apple.CFNetwork             0x00007fff85cc9e90 +[NSURLConnection(Loader) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 434
6   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8e3b4b7a __NSThread__main__ + 1345
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8fc2e2fc _pthread_body + 131
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8fc2e279 _pthread_start + 176
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8fc2c4b1 thread_start + 13

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff854b852e mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff854b769f mach_msg + 55
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff832bcb14 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 212
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff832bbfdb __CFRunLoopRun + 1371
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff832bb838 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 296
5   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8a01e8f7 _NSEventThread + 137
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8fc2e2fc _pthread_body + 131
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8fc2e279 _pthread_start + 176
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8fc2c4b1 thread_start + 13

Thread 6:: DYMobileDeviceManager
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff854b852e mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff854b769f mach_msg + 55
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff832bcb14 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 212
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff832bbfdb __CFRunLoopRun + 1371
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff832bb838 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 296
5   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8e3b6ab9 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 278
6   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8e4b245f -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) run] + 74
7   com.apple.GPUToolsMobileFoundation  0x0000000114bc389b -[DYMobileDeviceManager _deviceNotificationThread:] + 134
8   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8e3b4b7a __NSThread__main__ + 1345
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8fc2e2fc _pthread_body + 131
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8fc2e279 _pthread_start + 176
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8fc2c4b1 thread_start + 13

Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff854bd132 __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   com.apple.Xcode.DevToolsCore    0x000000010de1b866 -[XCBlockQueue _processBlocksInThreadSlotNumber:] + 456
2   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8e3b4b7a __NSThread__main__ + 1345
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8fc2e2fc _pthread_body + 131
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8fc2e279 _pthread_start + 176
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8fc2c4b1 thread_start + 13

Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff854bd132 __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   com.apple.Xcode.DevToolsCore    0x000000010de1b866 -[XCBlockQueue _processBlocksInThreadSlotNumber:] + 456
2   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8e3b4b7a __NSThread__main__ + 1345
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8fc2e2fc _pthread_body + 131
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8fc2e279 _pthread_start + 176
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8fc2c4b1 thread_start + 13

Thread 9:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff854bd132 __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   com.apple.Xcode.DevToolsCore    0x000000010de1b866 -[XCBlockQueue _processBlocksInThreadSlotNumber:] + 456
2   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8e3b4b7a __NSThread__main__ + 1345
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8fc2e2fc _pthread_body + 131
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8fc2e279 _pthread_start + 176
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8fc2c4b1 thread_start + 13

Thread 10:: Dispatch queue: Query work queue
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff854bd132 __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   com.apple.Metadata              0x00007fff862fbea6 _pushNotification + 687
2   com.apple.Metadata              0x00007fff862fb848 processUpdatesLocked + 10053
3   com.apple.Metadata              0x00007fff862f3056 tryProcessUpdates + 369
4   com.apple.Metadata              0x00007fff862f894e _MDQueryCallback + 329
5   com.apple.Metadata              0x00007fff862f87df __doQueryResultsCallback_block_invoke + 72
6   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff8d216323 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
7   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff8d211c13 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff8d215365 _dispatch_queue_drain + 1100
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff8d216ecc _dispatch_queue_invoke + 202
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff8d2146b7 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 463
11  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff8d222fe4 _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 91
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8fc2e6cb _pthread_wqthread + 729
13  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8fc2c4a1 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 11:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff854bd946 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8fc2c4a1 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 12:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff854bd946 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8fc2c4a1 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 13:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff854be67e read + 10
1   com.apple.DebugSymbols          0x00007fff86a7b600 BinaryData::ReadFile(UnixFD&, long long, unsigned long) + 368
2   com.apple.DebugSymbols          0x00007fff86a7ab9d CopyMatchingUUIDsForFileSystemRepresentation + 109
3   com.apple.DebugSymbols          0x00007fff86a7af57 CopyMatchingUUIDsInDSYMBundle + 471
4   com.apple.DebugSymbols          0x00007fff86a72163 UpdateCachedQueryResultsItem(__MDItem*) + 723
5   com.apple.DebugSymbols          0x00007fff86a71de8 UpdateCachedQueryResults() + 104
6   com.apple.DebugSymbols          0x00007fff86a7884b MDQueryDidFinishCallback(__CFNotificationCenter*, void*, __CFString const*, void const*, __CFDictionary const*) + 11
7   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff83368cbc __CFNOTIFICATIONCENTER_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER__ + 12
8   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8325a1b4 _CFXNotificationPost + 3140
9   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff832abc81 CFNotificationCenterPostNotificationWithOptions + 113
10  com.apple.Metadata              0x00007fff862fbf83 ___pushNotification_block_invoke + 151
11  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff832ca54c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 12
12  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff832bc655 __CFRunLoopDoBlocks + 341
13  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff832bc196 __CFRunLoopRun + 1814
14  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff832bb838 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 296
15  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff83371ed1 CFRunLoopRun + 97
16  com.apple.DebugSymbols          0x00007fff86a71b8f SpotlightQueryThread(void*) + 463
17  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8fc2e2fc _pthread_body + 131
18  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8fc2e279 _pthread_start + 176
19  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8fc2c4b1 thread_start + 13

Thread 14:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff854bd946 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8fc2c4a1 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 15:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff854bd486 __semwait_signal + 10
1   com.apple.CoreSymbolication     0x00007fff87494067 0x7fff87481000 + 77927
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8fc2e2fc _pthread_body + 131
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8fc2e279 _pthread_start + 176
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8fc2c4b1 thread_start + 13

Thread 0 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
  rax: 0x0000000000000000  rbx: 0x0000000000000006  rcx: 0x00007fff5bcc9728  rdx: 0x0000000000000000
  rdi: 0x000000000000130f  rsi: 0x0000000000000006  rbp: 0x00007fff5bcc9750  rsp: 0x00007fff5bcc9728
   r8: 0x0000000000001fff   r9: 0x00007ff6c0720ea0  r10: 0x0000000008000000  r11: 0x0000000000000206
  r12: 0x00007fff852c9ac0  r13: 0x00007ff6c4c92db0  r14: 0x00007fff72b19300  r15: 0x00007ff6c070aa00
  rip: 0x00007fff854bd282  rfl: 0x0000000000000206  cr2: 0x00007fff711dbfd8

Logical CPU:     0
Error Code:      0x02000148
Trap Number:     133


External Modification Summary:
  Calls made by other processes targeting this process:
    task_for_pid: 3
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0
  Calls made by this process:
    task_for_pid: 0
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0
  Calls made by all processes on this machine:
    task_for_pid: 3617
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0

VM Region Summary:
ReadOnly portion of Libraries: Total=413.5M resident=271.5M(66%) swapped_out_or_unallocated=142.0M(34%)
Writable regions: Total=1.4G written=182.5M(13%) resident=285.8M(21%) swapped_out=0K(0%) unallocated=1.1G(79%)
```

Tried reverting back my code too, as i was adding some UTIs in the `info.plist`.
It still crashes.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Please add relevant code so that it can be determined why this error occurs.

Comment: Thats what i am trying to figure out.
added this earlier
<key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
and the corresponding strings which i wanted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seemed to be some problem with **Project Format** in the **Project Document** of the projects.
U can find it in file inspector section of the projects targets part.

Changing it to xcode 3.2-compatible worked for me
Crashes for xcode 3.1-compatible and xcode 6.3-compatible though.